# Set UIDatePicker background color in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uidatepicker

When I set `background color` for `UIDatePiceker` in Interface Builder, nothing happens: the `backgroundColor` property is `nil`. But when I do it in code, it works fine. What's happening?

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: @SteveBaughman No, I gave up and did it in code. Maybe I'll look closer at it a week later, but certainly not now.

Answer (score 1):

A work around I'm using is just creating a UIView behind it with a white background. Adding the same constraints as the date view (I also added a height constraint which may be redundant for the UIDatePicker but I needed it for the view behind it).

May be more work than you're looking for but it works for me instead of coding an outlet and setting the background on viewdidload.